# Deploying MERN Application (using GraphQL) to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, graphql, mern

I just completed a MERN application following a great guide but it doesn't cover deployment. I am currently unsuccessful deploying, getting 'Application Error' at this link: https://enigmatic-castle-43725.herokuapp.com/

Here is the link to the git repo: https://github.com/Sciphr/Project-Manager

I have set up a 'heroku-postbuild' script with the following commands:

```
"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

My project setup is using Create-React-App in a 'client' folder, and then building the express server in a 'server' folder. I have the environmental variables setup in Heroku, and at one point the page loaded (just not the data from the GraphQL queries), but now it is back to 'Application Error'

I have a strong feeling the issue is with my index.js file in the 'server' folder, but I can't seem to understand exactly where the issue is. Thanks for any/all help anyone can give me, it really is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: "I have a strong feeling…"—feelings are usually less reliable than logs. What do they say? [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. On Heroku, you can check your logs by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Comment: That makes perfect sence, my apologies! I have now added a txt file in the Git repo with the logs from Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for updating! But please copy the logs directly into your question instead of posting them off-site. Self-contained questions are easier to answer, and much more likely to help other users in the future.

Comment: That's completely reasonable, I'll make sure to do that next time. I appreciate the advice! Out of curiosity, if the logs exceed the character limit of a comment, should I post multiple comments or is there a better way to do that? I want to make sure I do things as easy as possible for any future questions I may have

Comment: Thanks for being so receptive to feedback. Logs should go directly into your question, formatted as a code block. You can [edit] questions to add information as required using the "Edit" link below the tags. Comments can be hard to follow, have limited formatting options, and are only intended for short-term information. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Alright everyone who potentially saw this, my apologies as I did find the issue. This was my first time using GraphQL and I did not at all remember about the ApolloClient instance created in App.js, as that was the one place where you type out a specific URL. I also changed the position of my dotenv dependency from devDependencies to dependencies.

So before the uri was set to 'https://localhost:5000/graphql', which naturally I have now changed to my properly deployed link. Guess it would make sense to make it an ENV variable anyway.

Anyways thanks Chris sorry to take your time!